# Perl make string with two array elementwise

Tags: perl

I had two arrays and I wanted to join them together, something like:

```perl
arr1 = [temp1, temp2, temp3 ...]
arr2 = [k1, k2, k3 ...]
```

I wanted a string or an array something like

```perl
$str = "temp1.k1, temp2.k2, temp3.k3 ..."
```

or an array like

```perl
@arr = [temp1.k1, temp2.k2, temp3.k3 ...]
```

Either one would work.

Comment: Are `arr1` and `arr2` array references or just arrays? The square brackets suggest that it's an array reference but the arrays have no sigil (`$` or `@`).

Comment: [`List::MoreUtils::pairwise`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#pairwise-BLOCK-ARRAY1-ARRAY2) might be useful.

Answer (score 2):

For array references:

```
my @arr = map {$arr1->[$_] . "." . $arr2->[$_]} keys @$arr1;
```

For arrays:

```
my @arr = map {$arr1[$_] . "." . $arr2[$_]} keys @arr1;
```

To get a string instead of an array:

```
my $str = join ", ", map {$arr1[$_] . "." . $arr2[$_]} keys @arr1;
```

This concatenates each element of `@arr1` with a dot and the corresponding element of `@arr2` and then concatenates the joined elements together with a comma and a space.

If your perl is older than 5.14, replace `keys @arr1` in the above with `0 .. $#arr1`

Comment: `@arr1[$_]` should be `$arr1[$_]`

Answer (score 1):

Please inspect following code for a sample of possible solution.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @arr1 = qw/temp1 temp2 temp3 temp4/;
my @arr2 = qw/k1 k2 k3 k4/;
my(@arr,$str);

die "Arrays size mismatch" if @arr1 != @arr2;

for my $i ( 0..$#arr1 ) {
    push @arr, "$arr1[$i].$arr2[$i]";
}

$str = join(", ", @arr);

say $str;
say '-' x 35;
say Dumper(\@arr);
```